# How can I open an encrypted SQL Server Compat Edition database file?

Tags: passwords, sql-server-ce

Our customer provides us an dump file of an SQL Server Compact Edition.

The database is password-encrypted (probably by the team of the original project).

The file extension is : database.sdf

Is there a way to extract data from the dump file ? Or is there any password recovery tool for SQL Server Compact ?

Any hints would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In order open an encrSQL Server Compact edition file, you must know the password and add that to the connection string:
    Data Source=C:\temp\database.sdf;Password=mypassword

I do not know of any password recovery tool for SQL Server Compact